# how can i see all users who have unmask permissions on a db sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mask, masking

I have some columns that have been masked, how can I see the users who have the rights to see those fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The UNMASK permission is granted at the database level, so you can query the `sys.database_permissions` object to see which database principals have been granted that permission.

Script (adapted from https://sqlserverguides.com/sql-server-user-permissions/):

```
SELECT
    Username           = pri.name
   ,[User Type]        = pri.type_desc
   ,Permission         = permit.permission_name
   ,[Permission State] = permit.state_desc
   ,Class              = permit.class_desc
FROM
    sys.database_principals  pri
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.database_permissions permit ON
        permit.grantee_principal_id = pri.principal_id
WHERE permit.permission_name = 'UNMASK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this information in SSMS by right-clicking the Database in Object Explorer and selecting Properties > Permissions.